# Adwords "ga:adCost" metric with dimension "ga:dateHour" or "ga:hour"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

In the [Dimension & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) for the Google Analytics Reporting API v4, I'm able to select the metric `ga:adCost` together with either `ga:dateHour` or `ga:date`.

When now using the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to query these fields, on an account, where I can see data in the Google Analytics web application, I either get an empty result (for the dim `ga:dateHour`) or a result, where all metric values are `0` (in case of dim `ga:hour`)

The request body for the `ga:dateHour` case looks the following:

```
{
  "reportRequests": [{
    "viewId": "61030091",
    "dateRanges": [{
        "endDate": "2017-06-02",
        "startDate": "2017-06-01"
      }],
    "metrics": [{
      "expression": "ga:impressions"
    }],
    "dimensions": [{
      "name": "ga:dateHour"
    }]
  }]
}
```

What is going wrong here? Is there a possibility to get Adwords costs by hour via the analytics API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My explanation is that this is a bug in the Dimensinos & Metrics explorer. My assumption is that cost data from AdWords is brought into GA at a maximum granularity of day, which is why you see no data when you add the ga:hour dimension. When I try and create a custom report using the GA interface with the same dimensions/metrics, I also get an empty report, so this behaviour is consistent across the interface and API.

Comment: So this means, that the hourly data is simply 'not there'?

Comment: correct, when the cost data was imported into GA, they only imported it at a daily granularity. Again, this is my assumption based on observed behaviour. We would need someone from the GA team to comfirm.